# Thesis RSS hook?

Tags: theme-thesis

New to customizing Thesis for WP so things are going slow.

I was wondering if there is a hook for removing the rss subscribe on menu li?

Trying to put this in footer.

Thanks.

Comment: As Thesis is a commercial Theme, you should consult the support offerings provided by DIY Themes.

Comment: Assuming that I haven't already. Thanks for your input none the less.

Answer (score 1):

The frustrating thing about this problem (since the RSS subscribe menu item appears by default) is that the option to disable it is only visible when using the "Thesis Nav Menu" - which is now disabled by default, in favor of the WP nav menu system.

If you go to Thesis Site Options -> Navigation Menu -> Select Menu Type, you can switch menu systems, if only just long enough to see the "Feed Link" option appear below - now you can disable it!

Make sure you save changes, then open Select Menu Type again so you can switch back to the WP nav menu system.

The subscribe button is now gone!

Answer (score 0):

On your admin side bar there should be an item titled "Thesis" and there is a bunch of options. One of those options is `Feed link in Nav Menu` just un-check the box.

For more information visit the first result in google for `thesis remove rss menu link` [here](http://fourblogger.com/4-tips-to-remove-default-options-in-thesis-theme/)

Comment: According to DYI to remove RSS Subscribe from menu you have to be using DYI menu instead of Wordpress.  See blockquote:
http://diythemes.com/thesis/rtfm/include-feed-link-in-nav-menu
Since  Thesis menu is deprecated when Thesis 2.0 drops, prudent to change over to Wordpress menu. Not familiar with how to remove RSS this way, and no word from DYI yet.